# Can you create interactive functions in an Emacs Lisp macro?

Tags: macros, elisp

I'm trying to write a macro in emacs lisp to create some ‘helper functions.’

Ultimately, my helper functions will be more useful than what I have here. I realize that there may be better/more intuitive ways to accomplish the same thing (please post) but my basic question is why won't this work/what am I doing wrong:

```el
(defmacro deftext (functionname texttoinsert)
  `(defun ,(make-symbol (concatenate 'string "text-" functionname)) ()
     (interactive)
     (insert-string ,texttoinsert)))

(deftext "swallow" "What is the flight speed velocity of a laden swallow?")
(deftext "ni" "What is the flight speed velocity of a laden swallow?")
```

If I take the output of the macroexpand and evaluate that, I get the interactive functions I was intending to get with the macro, but even though the macro runs and appears to evaluate, I can't call `M-x text-ni` or `text-swallow`.

Answer (score 13):

This does what you want:

```
(defmacro deftext (functionname texttoinsert)
  (let ((funsymbol (intern (concat "text-" functionname))))
`(defun ,funsymbol () (interactive) (insert-string ,texttoinsert))))
```

Comment: intern did the trick. I didn't even need the let

(defmacro deftext (functionname texttoinsert)
  `(defun ,(intern (concatenate 'string "text-" functionname))  ()
     (interactive)
     (insert-string ,texttoinsert)))


I had tried intern before, but I think I had called it wrong.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, if you use `lexical-binding`, you don't need to use a macro:

```
(defun deftext (functionname texttoinsert)
  (defalias (intern (concat "text-" functionname))
    (lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (insert-string texttoinsert))))
```

Answer (score 4):

As has been pointed out, the solution is to use `intern` instead of `make-symbol`.

It's possible to create multiple independent symbols with the same name, but only one of them can be the *canonical* symbol for the given name -- i.e. the symbol you will obtain when you refer to it elsewhere.

`intern` returns the canonical symbol for the given name. It creates a new symbol *only* if no interned symbol by that name already exists. This means that it will only ever create one symbol for any given name<sup>1</sup>.

`make-symbol`, on the other hand, creates a new symbol every time it is called. These are *uninterned* symbols -- each one is a completely valid and functional symbol, but *not* the one which will be seen when you refer to a symbol by its name.

See: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Creating Symbols` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Because `defun` returns the symbol it sets, you can observe what's going on by capturing the return value and using it as a function:

```
(defalias 'foo (deftext "ni" "What is the flight speed velocity of a laden swallow?"))
M-x text-ni ;; doesn't work
M-x foo ;; works
```

or similarly:

```
(call-interactively (deftext "shrubbery" "It is a good shrubbery. I like the laurels particularly."))
```

The tricky part in all this -- and the reason that evaluating the expanded form did what you wanted, and yet the macro didn't -- is to do with exactly how and *when* (or indeed *if*) the lisp reader translates the name of the function into a symbol.

If we write a function foo1:

```el
(defun foo1 (texttoinsert) (insert-string texttoinsert))
```

The lisp reader reads that as text, and converts it into a lisp object. We can use `read-from-string` to do the same thing, and we can look at the printed representation of the resulting lisp object:

```el
ELISP> (car (read-from-string "(defun foo1 (texttoinsert) (insert-string texttoinsert))"))
(defun foo1
    (texttoinsert)
  (insert-string texttoinsert))
```

Within that object, the function name is the canonical symbol with the name "foo1". Note, however, that the return value we see from `read-from-string` is only the *printed representation* of that object, and the canonical symbol is represented only by its name. The printed representation does not enable us to distinguish between interned and uninterned symbols, as all symbols are represented only by their name.

(Skipping ahead momentarily, this is the source of your issue when evaluating the *printed* expansion of your macro, as that printed form is passed through the lisp reader, and what was once an uninterned symbol becomes an interned symbol.)

If we then move on to macros:

```el
(defmacro deffoo2 ()
  `(defun foo2 (texttoinsert) (insert-string texttoinsert)))

ELISP> (car (read-from-string "(defmacro deffoo2 ()
        `(defun foo2 (texttoinsert) (insert-string texttoinsert)))"))
(defmacro deffoo2 nil
  `(defun foo2
       (texttoinsert)
     (insert-string texttoinsert)))
```

This time the reader has read the *macro* definition into a lisp object, and within that object is the canonical symbol `foo2`. We can verify this by inspecting the object directly:

```el
ELISP> (eq 'foo2
           (cadr (cadr (nth 3
            (car (read-from-string "(defmacro deffoo2 ()
             `(defun foo2 () (insert-string texttoinsert)))"))))))
t
```

So for this macro, it is already dealing with that canonical symbol `foo2` *before* any macro call/expansion happens, because the lisp reader established that when reading the macro itself. Unlike our previous simple function definition (in which the function symbol was determined by the lisp reader as the function was defined), when a macro is called & expanded the lisp reader is *not* utilised. The macro expansion is performed using pre-existing lisp objects -- no reading is necessary.

In this example the function symbol is already present in the macro, and because it is the canonical symbol we could use `(foo2)` elsewhere in our code to call that function. (Or, had I made the definition interactive, use `M-x foo2`.)

Finally getting back to the original macro from the question, it's obvious that the lisp *reader* never encounters a function name symbol for the function it will define:

```el
ELISP> (car (read-from-string "(defmacro deftext (functionname texttoinsert)
        `(defun ,(make-symbol (concatenate 'string \"text-\" functionname)) ()
           (interactive)
           (insert-string ,texttoinsert)))"))
(defmacro deftext
    (functionname texttoinsert)
  `(defun ,(make-symbol
            (concatenate 'string "text-" functionname))
       nil
     (interactive)
     (insert-string ,texttoinsert)))
```

Instead this object produced by the lisp reader contains the expression `,(make-symbol (concatenate 'string "text-" functionname))`; and that backquoted expression will be evaluated at expansion time to create a new *uninterned* symbol which will be a part of the object created by that expansion.

In our earlier examples the resulting object had a car of `defun` (interned), and a cadr of `foo1` or `foo2` (both also interned).

In this last example, the object has a car of `defun` (interned) but a cadr of an *uninterned* symbol (with the name resulting from the `concatenate` expression).

And finally, if you *print* that object, the printed representation of that uninterned function symbol will be the symbol name, and *reading* that printed representation back by evaluating it would cause the function cell for the *canonical* symbol to be defined instead.

<sup>1</sup> In fact the `unintern` function can be used to unintern a symbol, after which calling `intern` for the same name *would* naturally create a new symbol; but that's not important for this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

It's been years, but I think you're probably missing an `fset` to define the function; see [the docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Eval-During-Compile.html#Eval-During-Compile) if you are wanting it a compile time too.