# Creation of similar functions using Lisp macro

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, metaprogramming

In my work i try using macro in Common Lisp and have some questions.
I have two functions

```
(defun when-tagflag ()
  (when (= tagflag 1)
   (setf tagflag 0)
   (push tagbuf taglist)
   (setf tagbuf "")))


 (defun when-attrflag ()
  (when (= attrflag 1)
   (setf attrflag 0)
   (push attrbuf attrlist)
   (setf attrbuf "")))
```

Very similiar functions. After several hours of experiments I got such a macro

```
defmacro when-flag (name)
 (let ((flag (read-from-string (concatenate 'string (string name) "flag")))
       (lst (read-from-string (concatenate 'string (string name) "list")))
       (buf (read-from-string (concatenate 'string (string name) "buf"))))
 `(when (= ,flag 1)
   (setf ,flag 0)
   (push ,buf ,lst)
   (setf ,buf ""))))


 > (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(when-flag "tag")))
 > (WHEN (= TAGFLAG 1) (SETF TAGFLAG 0) (PUSH TAGBUF TAGLIST) (SETF TAGBUF ""))
```

Inside when-flag  i use concatenate string and read-from-string , but i think my method not canonical . Are there more appropriate approaches to solving such a problem?

P.S. This solution doesn't work for me [Can you create interactive functions in an Emacs Lisp macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660555/can-you-create-interactive-functions-in-an-emacs-lisp-macro)

Comment: `(setf attrlist (push attrbuf attrlist))` is just `(push attrbuf attrlist)`.

Comment: @RainerJoswig thx for  tip :) i newbie in lisp)

Comment: I've changed the tag: the language is called Common Lisp, not Clisp.

Comment: Just as an FYI, this is tripping some warning bells for me. You're using multiple numeric flags similarly enough that you need a macro like this, and you seem to be mutating at least four global variables. If I had code like this, I'd look at it very carefully to see if there wasn't a better way of expressing my intent. Consider submitting it over at [CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) when you're done.

Comment: @Inaimathi Thank you for your comment. I agree that it is wrong. All when-functions part of closure. But i don't add this in my question. This is prototype for some tasks and i when i thought about refactoring i saw this similiar between this functions. i thought: "can macros help me in this task?"

Comment: The problem seems to be that you encoded parameters in function names.  While you can make this less painful through the answer to this question, the real solution is to put your flags, buffers and lists into a data structure, e. g. a hash-table.  That might be three hash-tables, or it might be one hash-table referencing objects that hold the three components for a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symbol names in Common Lisp are by default uppercase internally.

```
CL-USER 10 > (intern (concatenate 'string "TAG" "FLAG") "CL-USER")
TAGFLAG
:INTERNAL

CL-USER 11 > (intern (format nil "~:@(~AFLAG~)" "TAG") "CL-USER")
TAGFLAG
:INTERNAL
```

Example:

```
(defmacro when-flag (prefix &key (package-name "CL-USER"))
  (flet ((create-symbol (suffix)
           (intern (format nil "~:@(~A~A~)" prefix suffix)
                   package-name)))
    (let ((flag-sym (create-symbol "FLAG"))
          (list-sym (create-symbol "LIST"))
          (buf-sym  (create-symbol "BUF")))
      `(when (= ,flag-sym 1)
         (setf ,flag-sym 0)
         (push ,buf-sym ,list-sym)
         (setf ,buf-sym "")))))
```

Comment: Thank you) I tried symbols and intern function and now i find what were wrong. I used intern with lowercase string.
And what about read-from-string approach - this is correct solution?